# How to find the user who created a table in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to find the created by user for a table in Snowflake. Information_Schema tables only shows the role that owns it.

Going through the Query_History is laborious.

Thanks,
Sam

Information_Schema and Show tables command.

Answer (score 7):

random searches in snowflake.account_usage.query_history can be laborious, but targeted ones are fairly quick and easy, this should work for you.

```
SET dbName='DATABASE NAME HERE';
SET schemaName='SCHEMA NAME HERE';
SET tableName='TABLE NAME HERE';
SET create_dt=(
    SELECT MIN(created) 
    FROM snowflake.account_usage.tables 
    WHERE table_catalog = $dbName 
    AND table_schema = $schemaName 
    AND table_name = $tableName 
    AND deleted is null);

SELECT  * 
FROM   snowflake.account_usage.query_history
WHERE  query_text iLike '%CREATE%TABLE%'||$tableName||'%'
AND    execution_status = 'SUCCESS'
AND    start_time = $create_dt;
```

Comment: This answer is a good start for anyone to build on, but it's not correct to look at the database and schema name in the query history, because those don't reflect the database and schema that the table was created in, they only indicate the ones "in use" in the session that called the query.

Comment: Seub, isn't the point of the query to get the user that executed the query which resulted in the table being created? Presumably you would already know the database and schema because you are querying who created said table.

Answer (score 4):

Posting the query I came up with to find user/role of the person who created a table for anyone that wants to adapt it.

```
// anything older than 20 days ago
SET cutoff = current_date() - 20;

SELECT h.query_text,
       h.database_name,
       h.user_name,
       h.role_name,
       t.table_name,
       u.login_name
  FROM snowflake.account_usage.query_history h 
  LEFT JOIN snowflake.account_usage.users u
    ON u.name = h.user_name 
   AND u.disabled = FALSE 
   AND u.deleted_on IS NULL
  JOIN user_stage.information_schema.tables t
    ON t.created = h.start_time
 WHERE execution_status = 'SUCCESS' 
   AND start_time < $cutoff
   AND query_type LIKE '%CREATE_TABLE%'
   AND CONTAINS(UPPER(h.query_text), UPPER(t.table_name))
   AND t.created < $cutoff;
```