# How to get the user who created table in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

Is there any way to check the user name who created the table in snowflake database.

To previous questions in stack over flow some one suggested below query.
[How to find the user who created a table in Snowflake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58698596/how-to-find-the-user-who-created-a-table-in-snowflake)

but I am unable to run the query, showing below error

Error: SQL compilation error: Shared database is no longer available for use. It will need to be re-created if and when the publisher makes it available again.

After gone through some documentation in snowflake I understood it need share access
Please let us know if this share access can be granted to every end user to find the user name who created table ? is it recommended to grant to users.
if so how to grant access to user

or is there any alternative way to get this information.

Regards,
Srinivas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the following command to find your current role:

```
select current_role();
```

Then ask your account admin to grant access to the SNOWFLAKE database:

```
grant IMPORTED PRIVILEGES on database snowflake to role your_role_name;
```

Comment: We are able to execute the query but is there any native metadata table available in snowflake to get the information like who created the table.
In information schema tables, we able to find the role information from which table got created but not giving actual user info

Answer (score 0):

You can try information Schema. If you have access to that database then you should be good.

```
select user_name,query_text,*
from table(information_schema.query_history())
where contains(lower(query_text),'<your table name>')
  and query_type = 'CREATE_TABLE'
order by start_time;
```